# Users to retrieve order description once Paypal payment has been made

Tags: html, database, paypal

I have a "hotspot" system where the user pays through PayPal for Internet access. Once payment has been made, you are directed back to the hotspot and provided with your code.

The problem I am having is that people are forgetting or not writing their code down. I want them to go on my website and enter their Name, Email and Order Date and they are then provided with their code (which is the order description in PayPal).

I have only basic HTML knowledge but tend to be able to figure things out myself, this is going a bit far though.

Comment: I presume you would like users to receive a code via email. This is possible - _very_ basic code is available here: https://www.paypaltech.com/pdtgen/. To copy this to a database, you'll need to do some programming, though not much - give it a go?

Answer (score 0):

You could use IPN, to send the users their code to their email.  This way if they don't write it down they could go check their email and get the code.  Basically an IPN would be sent when the buyer completes a payment, once your IPN system confirms this you would just set it up to sent the users an email with their code.

Comment: You can find some code samples at https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623 and at https://www.paypaltech.com/SG2/ that may help you or give you something to build off of.